# super,this,static binding dynamic binding

Tags: java

Why `super` use static binding, but `this` use dynamic bind?
The code is on follows.

```
public class Person {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.print("Person 1");
    }
    public void method2() {
        System.out.print("Person 2");
    }
}

public class Student extends Person {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.print("Student 1");
        super.method1();
        method2();
    }
    public void method2() {
        System.out.print("Student2");
    }
}

public class Undergrad extends Student {
    public void method2() {
        System.out.print("Undergrad 2");
    }
}
```

When I enter follows in main method

```
Person u = new Undergrad();
u.method1();
```

The result is: `Student 1 Person 1 Undergrad 2`

Comment: Because that's exactly what `super` means.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What else did you expect? Isn't that what should happen?

Comment: If super didn't use static binding, it would become quite hard to access all the parent classes of an object, and it's designed to be made for it. Moreover, it would became very hard to expect how the program would behave.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a trivial question as few other answers may have implied.
There is descent explanation of this in [Learning Java book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-java/1565927184/ch06.html) :

> The usage of the super reference when applied to overridden methods of a superclass is **special**; it tells the method resolution system to stop the dynamic method search at the superclass, instead of at the most derived class (as it otherwise does).

When Undergrad calls method1(), since it is not overridden in Undergrad, method1() of Student gets called.

The questions focuses on these two lines in Student's method1:

```
    super.method1();
    method2();
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
    super.method1();
    this.method2();
```

Note: The dynamic object that called this function is Undergrad.

So in the second line - this.method2() **will be dynamically bound** to method2() of Undergrad. 
However in the first line - super.method1() **won't be dynamically bound** to Undergrad's super-class (which is Student), but will be statically (at compile time) bound to Student's parent (which is Person).

This is not as trivial as it seems, and the alternative (not correct) option of super.method1(); calling Undegrad's super class (Student) method1 is somewhat reasonable.